# How to host server on local PC(ubuntu) and set up virtual hosts

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am using Ubuntu and want to host a server on it.

What I want to do is

- Host server on local PC and set up virtual hosts on same PC
- in virtual host, have “myname.com” opened in browser

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walkthrough for LAMP installation for ubuntu.
You of course have more options than use Apache2 for example some light-httpd server will be sufficient.

Depending on your needs you can just install Apache2 or wole bundle.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Here is article from "Etel Sverdlov" about how to set and configure Apache virtual hosts.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts